# When I connect Firebase to my Flutter project, I get an error

Tags: android-studio, flutter

Hello I want to connect Firebase to my flutter app. When I write the code, I get an error.

> Error on line 29, column 3: Expected ':'.    ╷ 29 │   # The following
> adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.    │   ^    ╵
> Please correct the pubspec.yaml file at
> C:\Users\kludi\AndroidStudioProjects\flutter_app_sportkludik\pubspec.yaml

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
    firebase_core: "0.5.2"

  $ flutter pub get
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have added an extra space

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  firebase_core: "0.5.2"
```

Answer (score 1):

you have an extra space

```dart
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  firebase_core: "0.5.2"
```

Comment: it is not help.

Comment: @kludik000 please send a complete yaml file as it say there is error on line 29

Answer (score 1):

@xkxeeshankhan is right. Spaces are important in pubspec.yaml file. Please be careful while defining the firebase_core package. And, one more thing, you should not use (") character. It should look like this:

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter


  firebase_core: ^0.5.2
```

And the following command will **not** be in the pubspec.yaml file. You will run it on your terminal.

```
 flutter pub get
```

Comment: Also, where i need to write this code to initilization app  - ''final Future _initialization = Firebase.initializeApp();''?

Comment: That is another question. You should write the code of your page, too.

Answer (score 1):

@xkxeeshankhan

```
name: flutter_app_sportkludik
description: A new Flutter application.

# The following line prevents the package from being accidentally published to
# pub.dev using `pub publish`. This is preferred for private packages.
publish_to: 'none' # Remove this line if you wish to publish to pub.dev

# The following defines the version and build number for your application.
# A version number is three numbers separated by dots, like 1.2.43
# followed by an optional build number separated by a +.
# Both the version and the builder number may be overridden in flutter
# build by specifying --build-name and --build-number, respectively.
# In Android, build-name is used as versionName while build-number used as versionCode.
# Read more about Android versioning at https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/versioning
# In iOS, build-name is used as CFBundleShortVersionString while build-number used as CFBundleVersion.
# Read more about iOS versioning at
# https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CoreFoundationKeys.html
version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.7.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  firebase_core: "0.5.2"

  $ flutter pub get
  # The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.
  # Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.0

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter
# For information on the generic Dart part of this file, see the
# following page: https://dart.dev/tools/pub/pubspec

# The following section is specific to Flutter.
flutter:

  # The following line ensures that the Material Icons font is
  # included with your application, so that you can use the icons in
  # the material Icons class.
  uses-material-design: true

  # To add assets to your application, add an assets section, like this:
  # assets:
  #   - images/a_dot_burr.jpeg
  #   - images/a_dot_ham.jpeg

  # An image asset can refer to one or more resolution-specific "variants", see
  # https://flutter.dev/assets-and-images/#resolution-aware.

  # For details regarding adding assets from package dependencies, see
  # https://flutter.dev/assets-and-images/#from-packages

  # To add custom fonts to your application, add a fonts section here,
  # in this "flutter" section. Each entry in this list should have a
  # "family" key with the font family name, and a "fonts" key with a
  # list giving the asset and other descriptors for the font. For
  # example:
  # fonts:
  #   - family: Schyler
  #     fonts:
  #       - asset: fonts/Schyler-Regular.ttf
  #       - asset: fonts/Schyler-Italic.ttf
  #         style: italic
  #   - family: Trajan Pro
  #     fonts:
  #       - asset: fonts/TrajanPro.ttf
  #       - asset: fonts/TrajanPro_Bold.ttf
  #         weight: 700
  #
  # For details regarding fonts from package dependencies,
  # see https://flutter.dev/custom-fonts/#from-packages
```

Comment: remove this line
`$ flutter pub get`
this is a flutter command that you need to run from terminal